# ExoPlayer taking too long to play video

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am trying to play a video with exoplayer but it's taking too long to play.

How do I fix this issue?

PS - internet speed is not (so no speed issue)

```
private fun exoPlayerSetupVideo() {

        var trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector()
        //var loadControl =  DefaultLoadControl()
        var exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector)
        simpleExoPlayerView.player = exoPlayer
        var dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "VideoPlayer"))
        var videoSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url1))
        exoPlayer.prepare(videoSource)
        exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
    }
```

Comment: Hi! did you find any leads to get the streaming fast?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried some video urls inside the assets folder that the exoplayer demo project provide? If they play normally means that exoplayer is not the problem.